# How can you scale to arbitrary center points using ScaleTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf

If you try the following XAML code, you'll notice some strange behavior.

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="100" Height="100" 
               Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform CenterX="50" CenterY="50" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

The upper left corner of the blue rectangle is located at 50, 50 on the canvas.  Similarly, the center of the ScaleTransform is specified at 50, 50.  However, you'll note the resulting scaled canvas does not have the upper left corner of the rectangle in the center as I would expect.  My question is, why not?  And if this is the expected behavior of the ScaleTransform, what's the point?

**UPDATE**

Here is what I believe ScaleTransform is doing:

[image]

Tx is the translation value, Cx is the original center, and Sx is the scaling factor.  As you can see, the result should translate the rectangular "selection area" to match the viewport.  Except it doesn't.

Comment: +1 for a great question. By the way, your rectangle is missing its close tag, so this won't compile as is.

Comment: I"m not sure I understand the update. Where is the inner rectangle in that picture and why do you expect it's upper left corner to be in the center of the bigger box?

Comment: Ah, sorry yes it's confusing.  The inner rect is not the rect from the XAML.  The inner rect is the scaled area around the center point.  Think of it in terms of "rubber band" scaling wherein you select a region and (ignoring aspect ratio for now) want that region to inflate to fill the viewport.  This is also exactly what I'm trying to achieve although there are a number of reasons I'd like to it this way vs with scrolling, separate transforms, etc.

Comment: My question is, given the diagram you posted (which looks right to me), why would you expect a point in the inner (non-zoomed) rectangle, selected as the "center" to zoom from, would be at the center of the zoomed area?

Comment: Well if you think of the left edge of the inner rectangle as having to move (the translate part) to match the left edge of the outer rectangle and then filling the viewport (the scale part) then I would expect the center point of the inner rect would now be the center point of the outer rect.  FWIW it actually comes quite close, but is off by some mystery amount.  BTW, I really appreciate you talking this through with me!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49777/discussion-between-lordtakkera-and-jeff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this XAML, and it indeed worked as I would expect ScaleTransform to work.

Setting The "Center" property of a scale transform doesn't say: "Put this spot in the center of my control". It just says "Scale as if this was the center". It is easier to see in Rotate Transform (which uses a similar concept).

If you set up the same canvas with a RotateTransform, with the Center set to (0, 0), the whole canvas rotates around that point. If you set it to (50, 50), the canvas rotates around the upper left corner of the rectangle, etc.

This doesn't move the rectangle to the center of the canvas either, it is just the point to apply the transformation "from". So in scale transform, if my center is (0, 0), then all the scaling happens to the bottom and right. Put it at (50, 50) and it becomes a little bigger at the top and left, but the majority is still at the bottom and right. Put it at (150, 150) and all directions expand equally.

**Update**

I'm not sure about the reflected implementation, but here is another way to think about it. ScaleTransform is designed to simply scale a control. Scaling should not involve moving child elements relative to each other (that would be translation), this motion would be necessary to get the behavior you describe. The "center" variables are just the center of the transformation, they do not affect the position of an element relative to the parent (especially in a canvas, where these values are hard-coded.)

Also, all the transforms are "render" transforms, which means it just affects the display, the underlying control remains the same. No scaling you could ever do should make an object that is in the upper left corner of a parent object suddenly appear in the center.

**Update 2**
I believe I see what that final check is doing :).

To do a "centered" scale transform, you need to adjust your coordinate space. Scale operations in matrices (IIRC) are always applied from "0,0". According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.offsetx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the "offset" property:

> The OffsetX property is so named because it specifies the amount to
>   translate the coordinate space along the x-axis.

This obviously won't translate any controls, it is just adjusting the coordinate space for the transform.

**Update 3**
One more try...

I agree that changing the center of the scaling results in a non-uniform scale, and I could even imagine a scenario where that upper left corner appears to be in the middle of the scaled canvas. To do so, I would try putting the center in the other corner (at 250,250). This is going to be a lot of trial and error to find the exact point and scale factor that you need.

That being said, the question asked why the posted code didn't result in this. I believe that if you think about what "scaling from a center" actually results in, it will be obvious that any scale from Quadrant II  is not going to result in a point from Quadrant 2 being moved closer to the origin, it will always move further away (from what I discussed above).

Just to clarify, I am putting the "origin" at the center of the canvas.

Hopefully that makes sense. Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure why they don't shake out to the same thing.  If you look at the reflected implementation of ScaleTransform, centering is implemented as a translation.  Looking at their math it seems like it should work out the way I described except it doesn't.  They calculate the offset as equal to CenterX - CenterX * scale.  When I draw this out it makes sense that you need to adjust the center by the scaled center to "re-center" the canvas.

Comment: @Jeff, I wouldn't even know where to go to see the reflected implementation, but I tried to offer up another way to think about it so that the behavior you see makes sense. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: The link is horrendous but take a look near the bottom. http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Core/System/Windows/Media/ScaleTransform@cs/1/ScaleTransform@cs

Comment: Thanks for the link, I don't think I remember enough Linear Algebra to say exactly what i see that code doing :(. I am interested in hearing what you think about my reasoning though!

Comment: Me neither but again if you look at the last bit inside the final check, they are basically saying offset = CenterX - CenterX * scale, which seems like it should center the canvas; but is at least performing a translation.  This is really hard without a whiteboard :).  Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jeff, found a bit of information you might find interesting (see my update)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm confused because changing the center values clearly do translate the canvas (and all of its children).

Comment: Absolutely the canvas/controls move *relative to the window* but you asked why the rectangle wasn't centered in the canvas. Scaling won't change the "relative" position of the controls to each other or the canvas (the pixel count between them changes, but they are still located in the "same" place relative to each other).I Think that is the difference.

Comment: Uh, well I asked why the upper left-hand corner wasn't centered.  I understand that everything is still in the same place.  I'm wondering if I need to take the viewport into account or something.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. It is the same principle though. The upper left hand corner of the rectangle will maintain its position relative to the top left of the canvas (the distance will be scaled, of course). No scaling you can do should ever move that corner to the center of the canvas, it wouldn't be pure scaling at that point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you specify a non-zero center it is *not* pure scaling.  This is evident in the reflected code, which actually refers to it as a translation.

Comment: Let me know what you think about update 3, I thought about it a bit and realized that you are (at least partially) right.

Comment: Still confused.  Take a look at my update.  I tried best I could to draw out why there is a translation happening and why the translation should result in the "selection area" being centered in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to solve the same or similar problem, these fine folks figured it out:

[Smooth animation using MatrixTransform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988421/smooth-animation-using-matrixtransform)

It's not trivial and I believe the ScaleTransform is implemented somewhat incorrectly, making this the only clean approach.